# How would you remove all but the base folder of each string in a makefile variable?

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a variable something like:

```
VAR := obj/test obj/var/test2 bin/another/one bob/billy/joe
```

I want to get a variable that contains just the first folders, such that:

```
VAR2 = obj bin bob
```

I am thinking I need to use subst, but I can't figure out how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's the simplest solution but if:

1. the order of the result does not matter,
2. you use GNU make,
3. there are no spaces in your folder names,

something like:

```
VAR2 := $(sort $(foreach p,$(VAR),$(firstword $(subst /, ,$(p)))))
```

should make it.

- `$(subst /, ,$(p))` substitutes all `/` by space in the expansion of make variable `p`
- `firstword` keeps only the first word of the result, that is the first folder you are interested in
- `foreach` iterates over the words of `VAR` and sets make variable `p` to the current word
- `sort` removes duplicates (and... sorts).